# Java Convert UTC Date to local Date with Joda

Tags: java, jodatime, utc, localtime

This code is working, but I want to use Joda-Time

```
public static Date dateFromUTC(Date date){
        return new Date(date.getTime() + Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getOffset(date.getTime()));
    }
```

I tried this, but it's not working - what's the problem with this?

```
public static Date dateFromUTC(Date date){
        return new DateTime(date).withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault()).toDate();
    }
```

Comment: That looks wrong. What are you trying to obtain? Correcting the time zone offset of a date that has it set incorrectly? A `Date` doesn’t have a time zone, so there is no such thing as converting it from UTC to local time zone. See [All about java.util.Date](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/).

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Use *java.time* classes instead.

```
Instant.now()        // Capture current moment in UTC. Always in UTC, by definition.
```

…and…

```
ZonedDateTime.now()  // Capture current moment as seen through the wall-clock time of the people in the region of the time zone used by default in this JVM.
```

## Details

As others said, you misunderstood the concepts involved in these classes. A **`java.util.Date` represents a moment in UTC**, always in UTC<sup>†</sup>, never in some other time zone. So the code seen in the Question is non-sensical. You are working too hard!

## java.time

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Many of the concepts are similar between Joda-Time and java.time as both projects are led by the same man, Stephen Colebourne.

When you are ready to migrate, use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) in place of `java.util.Date`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

> instant.toString(): 2018-01-23T12:34:56.123456789Z

Instead of `java.util.Calendar`, use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to represent a moment seen through the wall-clock time of a particular region (a time zone).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;  // Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

As a shortcut, you can skip the `Instant` if you want only the zoned time.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;  // Capture the current moment as seen by people in a certain time zone.
```

You can get to UTC from there by extracting an `Instant` object.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Same moment, same point on the timeline, but viewed with the wall-clock time of UTC.
```

---

<sup>†</sup> Actually, there *is* a time zone assigned deep within a `java.util.Date` but is irrelevant to our discussion here. Confusing? Yes. One of *many* reasons to avoid the awful mess that is the old `Date`/`Calendar` and related legacy date-time classes.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
new DateTime(date, DateTimeZone.UTC)
    .toLocalDateTime() // value without timezone
    .toDateTime() // convert to default timezone
    .toDate();
```

Your code actually does nothing to the date, because `new DateTime(date)` creates a DateTime object with default timezone. And then you just convert it back to `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, read the article linked in the comments: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

A `java.util.Date` doesn't have a timezone. It actually represents a point in time: the number of milliseconds since unix epoch (Jan 1st 1970, at midnight, in UTC).

When you print the `Date`, though, it **uses** the JVM default timezone to convert the `Date` to date/time values, but the `Date` itself doesn't have a timezone.

That's why converting a `Date` object to another timezone doesn't make sense.

If you want to know the date (day, month, year) and time (hour, minute, second, millisecond) that corresponds to the `Date` in a specific timezone, then you can use Joda-Time:

```
// java.util.Date
Date date = new Date();

// the Date converted to UTC
DateTime utc = new DateTime(date, DateTimeZone.UTC);

// the Date converted to JVM default timezone
DateTime convertedToDefaultTz= new DateTime(date, DateTimeZone.getDefault());
```

The conversion can also be made using another `DateTime`:

```
DateTime convertedToDefaultTz = utc.withZone(DateTimeZone.getDefault());
```

Joda's `DateTime` has a timezone attached to it, so now it makes sense to convert to another one. But the `Date` objects returned by it will always be the same, because all of them represent the same instant (the same point in the timeline):

```
Date d1 = utc.toDate();
Date d2 = convertedToDefaultTz.toDate();
System.out.println(d1.equals(d2)); // true
```

All because - again - a `Date` doesn't have a timezone.